# PHP API wont return right data

Tags: php, api

So im using the spaceX api to try and understand retrieving data using php a bit more,

my base url is : https://api.spacexdata.com/v5/launches/

from here it returns:
[image]

from here i want the webcast link, but i cannot acces it somehow.

my current code:

```
$api_url = 'https://api.spacexdata.com/v5/launches/';

$json_data = file_get_contents($api_url);


$data = json_decode($json_data, true);
//var_dump($data);
$i = 0;
foreach ( $data as $launches)
{
    $i++;
    if($i > 2) break;
    var_dump($launches["fairings"],
            $launches["links"], '<br/>');
}
```

that returns: [image]

how can i return the 'webcast' url

Comment: `$launches["links"]["webcast"]` ??

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Post plain text

Comment: so i guess that if i copy pasted everyhthing it would be more clear for yall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$launches["links"]["webcast"]
```

You can chain your properties to go down the objects/arrays values... This is the same as doing

```
$links = $launches["links"];
$links["webcast"];
```